# After importing Spreadsheet to Sharepoint, insert text fields into "People Picker" column type

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010, import-from-excel

I have Infopath and Sharepoint 2010. I have imported data from a spreadsheet onto SharePoint and in the Excel sheet it had peoples' names on there. I created a people picker field and I was wondering why I can not just copy and paste the fields of the people into the "People picker" field? I was wondering if there is a workaround this problem. I have over 1,000 items that I need to transfer to the People picker field. I am avoiding in doing this manually. Is there anyway to complete this task programtically? Using C++ maybe? Thank you!

Comment: @pnuts I figured it out. I simply needed to make a People/ Group field from SharePoint and then just copy and paste the names.

Answer (score 1):

Make a People/ Group field from SharePoint itself and then just copy and paste the names from the text field into the People/ Group people.